# RazorLight for .Net Core how to setup encoding for DE lang

Tags: .net-core, razorlight

I have used RazorLight in my .Net Core project. And I need to parse Resourses.resx files with different languages. It works good for EN, but when I trying to parse DE lang(for example), I have some issues with some symbols. How can I setup correct encoding for RazorLight? Can't find any information about this.
Or please advice some lib like RazorLight for parsing razor templates for .net core with Resources.resx files

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use DotLiquid,like this

```
Template template = Template.Parse("hi {{name}}"); // Parses and compiles the template
template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { name = "tobi" })); // => "hi tobi"
```